# как убрать выделение сайта в VS?

Tags: visual-studio

как убрать выделение ссылки на сайт? (Visual Studio 2019)
[image: gift]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor

Тут выбираем либо конкретную категорию, например, C#, либо All Languages.

Снимаем чекбокс Enable single-click URL navigation